# Print a double(> than 17 digits) value without E notaion in Java

Tags: java

I have a requirement of printing a 22 digit number, but when i print it, JVM is using E notation.
I have tried BigDecimal class, printf(), String.Format(), but I didn't succeed. 
All I get is accurate till 17 digits, from 18th digit data is manipulated.
For example:

original number : 2333333333333333333333
output:           2333333333333333456252

Here is the Fragment of my Code. Hope this helps

```
double[] n = new double[T];
for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        n[i] = Double.parseDouble(scn.next());
    }
if(........){
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(n[i]).toPlainString());
System.out.printf("%.0f ", n[i]);
}
```

Comment: Post your code that doesnt work

Comment: C0nvert the data to string and then print it

Comment: BigDecimal should work if configured right.

Comment: Please, put the code that doesn't work. You may have a fail because converting to string and then print it or using BigDecimal should work.

Comment: If you do String.valueOf(2333333333333333333333d), that DOESN'T WORK

Comment: Big Decimal is providing accuracy of 17 digits only @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner

Comment: @JavA_LynX BigDecimal lets you specify arbitrary precision and rounding mode.

Comment: @JavA_LynX You are loosing precision because of conversion to Double. Just pass a String to BigDecimal constructor. Directly from Scanner.

Comment: Sorry for unclear code, but There are many if else statements after taking input and printing the value. @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in a double to the constructor of BigDecimal causing precision to be lost. Just use

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(scn.next()).toPlainString());
```

Comment: But If I remove parsing Inconvertible Types would occur, because n is double type and return type of next() is String.

Comment: don't use the formatter just print directly the value of BigDecimal

Comment: Sorry for unclear code, but There are many if else statements after taking input and printing the value.  @Reimeus

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
   final int NUM_BITS = 72; // 10^22 ~= 2^72

   final BigInteger bigNumber = new BigInteger(NUM_BITS, new Random());
   System.out.println("" + bigNumber);
```